# jQuery UI scale effect animation boundaries remain static during the animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When you click on the box, it scales down and only after it dissapears completely, the other boxes move onto its place. Is it possible to change this behaivour so that the boxes start to move proportionaly to the scaleed down element size so that the transition looks more natural?

http://jsfiddle.net/XuDxR/

```
<div id="d0">AAAAAA</div>
<div id="d1">AAAAAA</div>
<div id="d2">AAAAAA</div>
<div id="d3">AAAAAA</div>
<div id="d4">AAAAAA</div>​

$('div').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).effect("scale", {
        mode: 'hide', easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    }, 500);
});
​

div
{
display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$(this).animate({ width:0,height:0},  
                {
                  duration:500,
                  easing:'easeOutBounce',
                  complete:function(){
                      $(this).css('display','none');
                  }
                }
);
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm.